# Synthetic Control using CausalPy

Tags: causality, ab-test, causalimpact, synthetic-controls

I am using CausalPy (https://causalpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to implement synthetic controls for Bayesian Geo-Lift.

Goal is to test a business initiative/feature (on website) in let's say 1 EU country, and use other correlated countries as control to generate synthetic counterfactuals.

I have different KPIs that I want to measure like conversion rate, sales, profits etc. I am getting a fair bayesian r2 of >0.8 while using 9 controls. I am able to get the total treatment effects but can't get a day-level synthetic and observed data in a datafrme

Question is:

1. How can I get the above result in a data frame so I can make a dashboard (having daily impacts recorded after a test starts) out of it for users
2. Currently I can only input 9 controls and library throws an error when I use more than 9, not sure if it's only me
3. **Placebo Test**- I want to test my treatment effects statistically using placebo tests and get a p value to conclude if the results are significant. How can I do that here?

(FYI I tried using SparseSC as an alternative but Bayesian method (causalpy) gives me results that make more directional business sense)